# How can I embed a Flutter layout in my Android App using FlutterFragment with a custom entry point?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart, androidx

This feature I'm trying out in Flutter is called **Add-to-App**.

I read the instructions included in their [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app) on how I can add `FlutterFragment` as a section in my app.

As seen in the document [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-fragment?tab=add-fragment-kotlin-tab#add-a-flutterfragment-to-an-activity-with-a-new-flutterengine), I should be able to add my `newFlutterFragment` just like how I add normal `Fragment` classes in Android.

```
// Create and attach a FlutterFragment if one does not exist.
if (flutterFragment == null) {
  var newFlutterFragment = FlutterFragment.createDefault()
  flutterFragment = newFlutterFragment
  fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(
      R.id.fragment_container,
      newFlutterFragment,
      TAG_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT
    )
    .commit()
}
```

The examples we're pretty much straightforward, however, as per checking (Github and SO), it only works when you are warming up a `FlutterEngine` using the **`main`** or **default entry point**.

[image: image-1]

Unfortunately, whenever I try adding my own `FlutterFragment` using a **custom entry point**, it doesn't seem to accept the type of object I'm passing in the `.add(<INVALID_TYPE>,...,...)` method of the `FragmentTransaction`.

[image: image-1]

Is there by any chance that I could still use `FlutterFragment` as the container for the Flutter section view I have?

Setup

- Android depend on Flutter module's source code (**Option B**)
- Android project with AndroidX

Environment

- Flutter: v1.12.13+hotfix.5 (stable)
- Dart: v2.4.0
- OS: macOS Catalina v1.14.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What went wrong?**

As of the moment, if you are using **AndroidX**, the only way you can use `FlutterFragment` in embedding your Flutter layout is when it is added as an **Android Archive (AAR)** in your dependencies.

I've previously opened an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36984) in Github regarding this concern, and it is still open at the time of writing.

Adding Flutter as an AAR dependency has both pros and cons. With AAR, your team does not need to have Flutter SDK installed in their local machine nor required to install Dart SDK. However, since AAR files are compiled artifacts, your team may not be able to edit the project's Flutter source code during development.

[Here's](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) the documentation on how you can setup your Android project with your Flutter source code added as an AAR module.

> But why really use AAR?

Under the hood, `FlutterFragment` and some (if not all) of the classes under 
`io.flutter.embedding` are still using the support libraries and not AndroidX, there is a **mismatch in the dependencies**. With AAR and with your [jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) enabled during **compilation**, the AAR output of your Flutter will now use equivalent AndroidX libraries, something you don't expect to happen during **runtime** .

> But, I need my team to work on some Flutter app features simultaneously with some Android app project changes.

Well, since you can't use `FlutterFragment` in that particular type of setup, you can still use `FlutterView`, especially if you are only showing a portion of your Flutter layout in your Android app.

**feature_fragment.kt**

```
portfolioEngine?.let { flutterEngine ->
    // Start executing Dart code to pre-warm the FlutterEngine.
    // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Launch-Flutter-with-non-main-entrypoint
    flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
        DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint(
            FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(),
            "customEntryPoint"
        )
    )

    // Cache the FlutterEngine to be used by FlutterActivity.
    FlutterEngineCache
        .getInstance()
        .put("SOME_FLUTTER_ENGINE_NAME", flutterEngine)

    // Add the Flutter layout
    flutterView = FlutterView(context)
    flutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    flutterContainerView?.removeAllViews() // Only if deemed necessary
    flutterContainerView?.addView(flutterView)
}
```

**feature_layout.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flutterContainerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**But, there's a small catch...**

One of the benefits using `FlutterActivity` or `FlutterFragment` over `FlutterView` is the ease of managing the lifecycle of your Android and Flutter code simultaneously. Don't worry, you can still handle how your Flutter code will behave by managing its lifecycle using the attached `FlutterEngine`.

**Further reading**

- https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/FlutterEngine.html#getLifecycleChannel
- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup